# Scaling an object up and down

Tags: ratio

I have a drawing that is $7.2$ cm tall.  The original drawing used a scale of $1$ cm: $13$ inches.  According to that scale the object would be $7$ ft. $8$ in. tall in real life.  How do I figure out what scale to use to make it $5$ feet tall?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from the question what is to be altered. Here are a couple of alternatives:-

Keep the scale the same and redraw the object. Then you would need a height of $\frac{60}{13}=4.6$ cm.

Keep the drawing the same and state a new scale. Then a drawing of 7.2 cm would represent 60 inches and so the scale would be 1 cm :8.33 inches.

Comment: My answer was what you said 1cm:8.33 inches but the teacher said that I can't have a repeating number as a measure and to use cm:ft instead of cm:in.  That makes no sense to me and i'm completely lost.

Comment: The original question is Cate drew an animal that she wants to create.  She said that it would obviously be bigger than the drawing because she used a scale of 1cm:13 inches.  Based upon Cate's drawing how tall would this animal be in real life?  The drawing is 7.2 cm tall so I came up with 7 ft. 8 in. tall which the teacher said was correct.  The next question that i'm stuck on is Libby suggested they try to make the new animal exactly 5 ft tall.  What scale should they use to go with her idea?  I can only come up with an answer with a repeating number.

Comment: In that case, I am also stuck! Whether you use inches or feet you will have a recurring decimal because the number 72  (from the 7.2)  has a factor of 9. A sensible response would be to use a scale of 1cm:8.3 inches. this gives an answer extremely close to 5 foot.